# How to simplify the command : four same structures?

Tags: command-line, bash, ntp

```
ntpdate 110.75.186.247 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log ||  ntpdate 110.75.186.247 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log || ntpdate 203.123.48.218 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log|| ntpdate 103.16.199.21  >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

I have tried two method,none of them succeed.

```
ntpdate 110.75.186.247  ||  ntpdate 110.75.186.247  || ntpdate 203.123.48.218 || ntpdate 103.16.199.21  >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
ntpdate 110.75.186.247  ||  ntpdate 110.75.186.247  || ntpdate 203.123.48.218 || ntpdate 103.16.199.21  &&>> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

How to simplify the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple `for` construct:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for ip in 110.75.186.247 110.75.186.247 203.123.48.218 103.16.199.21; do
    out="$(ntpdate "$ip" 2>/dev/null)" && echo "$out" >>/var/log/ntpdate.log && break
done
```

Or saving IP addresses in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
ips=( 110.75.186.247 110.75.186.247 203.123.48.218 103.16.199.21 )
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    out="$(ntpdate "$ip" 2>/dev/null)" && echo "$out" >>/var/log/ntpdate.log && break
done
```

---

Even simpler, get rid of the intermediate variable (thanks @kos):

```
#!/bin/bash
ips=( 110.75.186.247 110.75.186.247 203.123.48.218 103.16.199.21 )
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    ntpdate "$ip" 2>/dev/null >>/var/log/ntpdate.log && break
done
```

Comment: Also simply `ntpdate "$ip" >>/var/log/ntpdate.log 2>/dev/null && break`

Comment: kos' structure is more simple and more readable,@heemayl  what does  `out=` mean?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature `out` is a variable that stores the STDOUT of the `ntpdate` command..if you want you can replace that with what kos has written..thats simpler..

Comment: @kos distracted enough to miss that :|

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if the file `.bash_aliases` exists in your home directory with `ls -a ~/.bash_aliases`
   (if not run the text editor of your choice, which is in my case `nano ~/.bash_aliases`)
2. Add the following line into that file:
   `alias update-time='ntpdate 110.75.186.247 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log || ntpdate 110.75.186.247 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log || ntpdate 203.123.48.218 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log || ntpdate 103.16.199.21  >> /var/log/ntpdate.log'`
3. Save and exit the editor
4. Now you simply can run the command `update-time` and rest is magic :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the construction

```
ntpdate 192.0.2.1 || ntpdate 203.0.113.2 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

is that `>>` only applies to the last command. You can address that by using a parenthesis around the commands like this:

```
( ntpdate 192.0.2.1 || ntpdate 203.0.113.2 ) >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

You may think that typing `ntpdate` multiple times is redundant, and it should be possible to eliminate that. You can eliminate the repetition of `ntpdate` by using a loop. Though in your specific case the command is so simple, that the use of a loop introduce more complexity than it eliminates:

```
for IP in 192.0.2.1 203.0.113.2
do
    ntpdate "$IP" && break
done >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

Alternatively it may be that your original problem is better solved by invoking `ntpdate` only once with multiple server addresses:

```
ntpdate 192.0.2.1 203.0.113.2 >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```